# NSRectFill in NSTextView is overwritten by text

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

When using either NSRectFill or NSBezierPath.fillRect to draw a block over some text in an NSTextView, the text seems to go over my rectangle. I.e. there is just a sliver of the rectangle peeking out from behind the text I'm supposed to be overwriting. How can I ensure that I'm drawing the rectangle after the text is drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subclassed NSTextView. First, draw the text with the super and then draw your own stuff .

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSRectFill(yourOwnRect);
}
```

Comment: And this is the only correct way to do it. Drawing into the view from a controller is never reliable and violates separation of concerns—drawing is the view's job.

Comment: Bingo, that did the trick. I actually had tried drawing from within drawRect: before, but didn't realize the coordinate system was different from within that method as opposed to the rest of my code and incorrectly thought the drawing wasn't working there either. Thanks!